# Combining multiple different observables into one observable

Tags: swift3, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I have problem with adopting RxSwift to my application. My problem is:
If I have many input signals (Variables with different elements) that can be change by user and from this changes I want to build one Observable signal. I think I should use some sort of Combination operator but for example combineLatest only allows for two parameters to combine.

Let's look at example of inputs and outputs that I have.

```
import RxSwift
import RxCocoa

class ModelView {

    private let api: ApiType

    // inputs
    let inType: Variable<MWItemQueryType>
    let inFilterRetailers: Variable<Set<MWRetailer>>
    let inFilterColors: Variable<Set<MWColor>>
    let inFilterPriceRanges: Variable<Set<MWPriceRange>>

    // outputs
    let outQuery: Observable<MWItemQuery>

    init(initialType: MWItemQueryType, api: ApiType) {
        self.api = api
        self.inType = Variable(initialType)
        self.inFilterRetailers = Variable(Set<MWRetailer>())
        self.inFilterColors = Variable(Set<MWColor>())
        self.inFilterPriceRanges = Variable(Set<MWPriceRange>())

        // TODO How to setup outQuery signal here
    }
}
```

So I have problem with setup outQuery that emits signals `MWItemQuery`. The `MWItemQuery` signal must be emitted when one of the input parameters changed. The `MWItemQuery` is then emitted to the api to fetch data from server with the most recent filters selected by the user. I have a lot of other input filter signals and I don't know if any operator can help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`combineLatest` can accept more than 2 parameters!

Try:

```
Observable.combineLatest(inType.asObservable(), inFilterRetailers.asObservable(), inFilterColors.asObservable(), inFilterPriceRanges.asObservable())
    { type, filterRetailers, filterColors, filterPriceRanges in 
        // do something with your data
    }
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .shareReplay(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [combineLatest](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxSwift/Observables/CombineLatest%2Barity.swift) operator, it can combine 2..8 `observables`.
There are different version to take different number of `observables`.

Comment: Hi @beethOven, combineLatest works if params count is more than one, but suppose i have only one parameter, then how should i pass it? For eg.

Stream<String> get cityName => _cityName.stream.transform(validateCity);
Stream<bool> get submitValid => Observable.combineLatest(cityName, (c) => true);

Here, i want to send "cityName" params to server, how should i use "combineLatest" ?

Comment: Hi @Annu, en.., if the params count is only one. there is nothing to combine. you don't need `combineLatest ` operator. just use normal operator to transform the observable. that's enough. `Observable.combineLatest(cityName, (c) => true)` this is just a map operator `cityName.map((c) => true)`, is it?